# Use Downscoped Access Token with CredentialAccessBoundary in google-cloud-storage (node)

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to use a [downscoped access token with a credential access boundary rule](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/downscoping-short-lived-credentials#creating) with the google storage node client. I've been able to obtain a downscoped token. I then build the Storage service and pass a new `AuthClient` with the downscoped access token in the config.

When I request a resource from the storage bucket, the default credentials are being used instead of the downscoped access token from the custom `AuthClient`:

```js
import {Storage} from "@google-cloud/storage"
import {GoogleAuth, OAuth2Client} from 'google-auth-library'
import {CredentialAccessBoundary, DownscopedClient} from "google-auth-library/build/src/auth/downscopedclient"

const auth = new GoogleAuth()

const cab:CredentialAccessBoundary = {
    accessBoundary: {
        accessBoundaryRules: [
            {
                availablePermissions: [
                    "inRole:roles/storage.objectViewer"
                ],
                availableResource: "//storage.googleapis.com/projects/_/buckets/test-data",
                availabilityCondition: {
                    expression: "resource.name.startsWith('projects/_/buckets/test-data/objects/specific/specific.txt')"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}

const {credential,projectId} = await auth.getApplicationDefault()

const dsc = new DownscopedClient(credential,cab)
const downscopedToken = await dsc.getAccessToken().token

const sClient = new OAuth2Client({

})
sClient.setCredentials(
    {
        access_token: downscopedToken

    })

if (downscopedToken) {
    const storage = new Storage({
        clientOptions: {
            sourceClient: sClient
        }
    })
    const resp = await storage.bucket("test-data").file("specific/specific.txt").download()
}
```

Comment: 1) How did you determine that the wrong credential is used? 2) Is Uniform bucket-level access enabled on the bucket?

Comment: @JohnHanley 1) I tested accessing a file outside of the access boundary 2) Access is uniform.

Comment: Is your storage public (allUsers allowed)?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere No. I manually tested the actual token generated from the downscoped client with curl and the restrictions work as expected. So the only conclusion I can draw is that the clientOptions I am specifying for the storage object are being ignored completely.